# Moment.js undefined object reference on ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to make a simple booking calendar using Eonasdan's bootstrap-datetimepicker which is built upon `moment.js` library for which I included localization file. I set up a basic linked pickers input fields and a button to send an e-mail with the dates using simple ajax request. However, upon submitting the form, I get the following error:

> // locale-hr.js (line 89, col 1)
>
> TypeError: this is undefined switch (this.day()) {

Excerpt from the file (lines 88-102):

```
nextWeek : function () {
    switch (this.day()) {
        case 0:
            return '[u] [nedjelju] [u] LT';
        case 3:
            return '[u] [srijedu] [u] LT';
        case 6:
            return '[u] [subotu] [u] LT';
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 4:
        case 5:
            return '[u] dddd [u] LT';
    }
},
```

No e-mails are sent but dates are fetched from the calendar.

This is my ajax file:

```
$(function() {
    $("#reservationForm").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = "../bin/reservation.php";

        // stores dates from each calendar
        var date1 = $("#datetimepicker1").data("DateTimePicker").date();
        var date2 = $("#datetimepicker2").data("DateTimePicker").date();

        $.ajax({             
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: { date1: date1, date2: date2 },
        }).done(function(response) {
            alert("Msg sent");
        });                     
    });
});
```

And the PHP file:

```
<?php
    if ( empty($_POST['date1']) || empty($_POST['date2']) ) {
        echo ERROR_NO_ARGS;
        return false;
    }

    $date1 = $_POST['date1'];
    $date2 = $_POST['date2'];

    $to = 'my@email.com';
    $email_subject = "Title";
    $email_body = "Selected dates:" . "From $date1 to $date2";
    $headers = "From: Contact form\n";      
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

    return true;            
?>
```

It's pretty basic stuff as you can see. I'd like to know what am I missing in here so that locale-hr.js has no object to reference or if I'm doing something wrong or if this is known issue that needs to be fixed (Google didn't offer me anything of sort). Here's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4zuxy4e/1/) but without ajax call as I never used fiddle before and don't know how to set it up at the moment. I might come back later to figure it out and add it.

If I should expand the question, please inform me. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work with another locale (e.g. english)?

Comment: Hm, tried with en-gb and it seems to pass the above error but another shows up:

`TypeError: this is undefined
...ts).parseZone()}function _b(a,b,c){var d=this._calendar[a];return"function"==typ...` - (moment.min.js line 6 col 20621)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eonasdan's bootstrap-datetimepicker [`date`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) method returns a [moment object](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/), so you are trying to send to your server an object that jQuery cannot serialize (see [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `data` section). You have to change the type you send to your server, you can:

- pass a string using moment [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) (if you need you can specify format). Your code will be: `data: { date1: date1.format(), date2: date2.format() }`
- pass milliseconds using moment [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/). Code: `data: { date1: date1.valueOf(), date2: date2.valueOf() }`
- pass seconds using moment [`unix()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/). Code: `data: { date1: date1.unix(), date2: date2.unix() }`

Comment: Great and helpful info. I thought the function to get date from the calendar already returned it as moment object so I didn't really think about formatting it again. I'll mark this as accepted answer. Thanks VincenzoC.

Answer (score 0):

possible there are some bugs:

updated fiddle :

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/dssoft32/d4zuxy4e/2/`
```

```js
// Template JS

var fnMain = function(){

    // Calendar localization
    var hr = moment.locale('hr', {
        days: ["Ponedjeljak", "Utorak", "Srijeda", "Četvrtak", "Petak", "Subota","Nedjelja"],
        weekdaysShort: ["Pon", "Uto", "Sri", "Čet", "Pet", "Sub","Ned"],
        weekdaysMin: ["Po", "Ut", "Sr", "Če", "Pe", "Su", "Ne"],
        months: ["Siječanj", "Veljača", "Ožujak", "Travanj", "Svibanj", "Lipanj", "Srpanj", "Kolovoz", "Rujan", "Listopad", "Studeni", "Prosinac"],
        monthsShort: ["Sij", "Velj", "Ožu", "Tra", "Svi", "Lip", "Srp", "Kol", "Ruj", "Lis", "Stu", "Pro"],
        today: "Danas",
        }
    );


    var enumerateDaysBetweenDates = function( startDate, endDate ) {
        var dates = [];
      
        while (startDate<= endDate) {
            dates.push(startDate.format('D/M/YYYY'));
            startDate.add(1,  'days');
        }

        return dates;
    };


    var formatDisabledDates = function( dateSet ) {
        var newSet = [];

        for( var i=0; i < dateSet.length; i++ ) {

            newSet.push( moment( dateSet[i], "D/M/YYYY") );

        }

        return newSet;

    }


        var fromDate = moment("10/07/2016", "D/M/YYYY"); 
        var toDate = moment("21/07/2016", "D/M/YYYY"); 

              var results = enumerateDaysBetweenDates(fromDate, toDate);

    //});

    var disabledSet = formatDisabledDates( results );
    console.log( disabledSet );

    var chckDate;

    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
     useCurrent: false, 
     allowInputToggle: true,
     viewMode: 'days',
        //minDate: moment(),
  locale: hr,
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        disabledDates: disabledSet
    }).on("dp.change", function (e) {
        chckDate = $(this).data("DateTimePicker").date();
        chckDate = chckDate.format('DD. MM. YYYY');
        
    }).on("dp.show", function (e){
        $("[data-day*='"+ chckDate + "']").addClass("startFrom");

    });

    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false,
        allowInputToggle: true,
        viewMode: 'days',
  locale: hr,
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        disabledDates: disabledSet
    }).on("dp.change", function (e) {
    //
    }).on("dp.show", function (e){
        $("[data-day*='"+ chckDate + "']").addClass("startFrom");
    });

        










} // fnMain endDate



$( document ).ready( fnMain );
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.input-group {
    margin-top: 20px;
}


.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.disabled, .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.disabled:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #777;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.startFrom, .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.startFrom:hover {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/locale/hr.js"></script>


<div class="container">

    <form id="reservationForm">
      <div class='col-md-6'>
      
      <!-- FROM -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- TO -->
      <div class='col-md-6'>
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                  </span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="logdates" type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Now that you mention, I see <!doctype> related error in the fiddle with hr.js being marked as source. `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

I tried implementing the changes you made to JS file but it's all the same.